# How to get image from gallery by using Intent In android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, imageview

How to get image from gallery and set that image to Imageview .

I was trying to do this but Intent not set the Image in Image View
and not showing kind of error.

can any one know how to do this ??

**My java code**

```
public class pratice extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView img1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pratice);
        Button check=findViewById(R.id.check);
        img1=findViewById(R.id.noticeimgview);
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent pickimg1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickimg1, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.e("URI",":"+uri);
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

**and my xml Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".pratice">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="check"
        android:id="@+id/check"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/noticeimgview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</LinearLayout>
```

============================================================================

Comment: Pass the `Uri` to your preferred image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso) and have it load the image into your `ImageView`.

Comment: And please remove the rubbish from the end of your post; filler text is not needed.

Comment: @CommonsWare I try picasso and glide as well but both are not showing the gallery image !!

Comment: @Ollie I do this because i not able to post this question and  Stackoverflow show error that why i do this .

Comment: @fezkhan Oh, the "mostly code" error?  Maybe a 2K+ user can fix that.

Comment: @Ollie can you please fix this if you are under that 2k+ user who able to solve this , I tried all the things but it did not show the image on ImageView.

Comment: Removed tag 'android-studio' as that is for problems/questions about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Comment: I don't believe there are no errors. You just aren't seeing them. Try not filtering the logcat. Also try replacing `e.printStacktrace()` with `Log.e("MyAppName", "Exception: ", e)`

Comment: @DavidWasser thanks for suggestion but my logcat is clear and their is no exception in Gallery intent